# Longer term logrotate

Tags: logrotate

Does anyone know what the config would be for keeping log files for 8 months but compressing them every day?

I got this:

```
/500Gb/wireshark/log/*
{ 
    rotate 240 
    daily 
    size 1000M           
    compress  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To keep log files for 8 months you would need to use the `maxage` parameter, with a parameter that counts in days. Strictly it's not possible to keep log files for exactly 8 months, but the approximation of 243 days might be acceptable.

As far as I have ever been able to tell, the difference between `rotate` and `maxage` is that `rotate` keeps N log files regardless of the number created per day, whereas `maxage` keeps log files for N days regardless of the number created.

```
/500Gb/wireshark/log/*
{ 
    maxage 243
    daily
    size 1000M
    compress
    delaycompress
}
```